# desktop-save doesn't save file names with emoji properly

Tags: unicode, desktop

`desktop-save-in-desktop-dir` doesn't save file names that include glyphs from upper unicode range like emoji characters properly. By "upper", I mean "greater" like one with a code point `1F604` instead of `0022`.

For example, when I have a file that has the title like ".txt" opened in a frame and I run `desktop-save`, it saves its file name as " .txt" in the `emacs-desktop` file and when I `desktop-read,` it just opens a `*scratch*` buffer instead of the ".txt" file.

My copy is a desktop version. 24.5 (9.0) downloaded from [GNU Emacs For Mac OS X](https://emacsformacosx.com/)

How can I get around this bug? I need to name certain files like this and not being able to use commands like `desktop-save` to save sessions would really slow down my workflow.

Comment: Sounds like a candidate for `M-x report-emacs-bug`. Especially if you can provide a recipe to reproduce the problem, starting with `emacs -Q` (no init file).

Comment: @Drew No workaround for this? Would it be hard to make my own version of `desktop-save-in-desktop-dir`? Why does this not handle unicode glyphs properly? I looked at `emacs-desktop` file where the command saves desktop info in, and other unicode glyphs are garbled too. They are converted into weird combinations of other irrelevant unicode glyphs.  Garbled ones can be loaded properly though. Upper unicode glyphs are all converted to just spaces.

Comment: @Drew And what would happen if I reported this as a bug? I've never done it before. I'd like to use this old copy because I found that newer versions had some problems in my environment in the past. So even if this bug that doesn't seem to be really important to other people is fixed in future versions, problems would remain in my environment...

Comment: If you report it as a bug it is likely that one or more people will take a look at it. If it is a bug then it should be reported (IMO), so that there is a greater chance that it will be fixed. You can likewise (separately, unless closely related) report whatever other problems you have with the current code that you don't have with an older version. If you don't report the problem then an alternative is to fix it in your own version of the code. That might help you, but how will it help others? (You could then propose updating Emacs equivalently - by providing a patch via `report-emacs-bug`.)